Why are users allowed to upvote their own Community Bot comments?
When doing my daily reviews across the network, I the often leave a pre-written, generic Community Bot comment on questions/answers.
But once, I accidentally upvoted my own Bot comment. And obviously, you can’t upvote your own “normal” comment.
Which leads me to ask this question purely out of curiosity. Because this is not a criticism; I don’t see anything wrong with  the way things are.
In fact, if a user has the privilege of being able to access reviews they should be responsible enough not to abuse the system.

I don't see what sort of answer you're looking for. Community is a different user than you. You can vote on comments by other users. Yes, this could be prevented but it's a lot of effort for...what exactly? For "I don’t see anything wrong with the way things are."?


Users are able to upvote comments of other users.
The Community user is different than you.

Therefore, the system allows you to upvote comments from Community as per the rules the system follows.

"The Community user is different than you" is not really true though. You instructed the bot to post the comment, therefore it is your comment, and the Community user is you at that moment, just anonymous. Implementation-wise it is a different user, but behavior-wise it is just you.

@Marijn It's a different user. I don't know why is there a need to nitpick. Quite clearly not the same user at the system level. Different name, different avatar, different action history. That Community happens to be carrying out an action you instructed it to, doesn't mean it's you. My statement is not flawed. You are trying to impose other definition there which seems to be "Community is carrying out an action on behalf of a different user which makes the action owner transferable". But if I quote somebody, I don't become them. Community is not "me" by saying something instead of me.
